# RichTextUploadingField in django 2.2.6 not show in admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, ckeditor5

i have a problem with my website that is the ckeditor filed when i use RichTextUploadingField it not show in admin panel , but when i use RichTextField it work and show perfect in admin panel but i want the RichTextUploadingField to upload pic so what is the problem here and how to fix it ..

models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class Android(models.Model):
    app_content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True,null=True)
```

urls.py:

```
path('ckeditor', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "media/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join('/home/myapp/public_html/static')
```

Comment: This is not related to django-rest-framework

Comment: are you using **django-ckeditor** ?

Answer (score 1):

You can either keep Django 2.2 and downgrade the django-ckeditor version to 5.8.0 (other version might work as well but 5.8.0 works for me)

Or migrate to Django 3.2 and upgrade django-ckeditor to >= 6.4.0